# Как перебрать правильно этот словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список со вложенными словарями

```
GRADEBOOK = [
    {'name':'Maksim Fedartsou',
     'subjects':
        {'math':9,'language':5,'history':8,'foreignl':9}},
    {'name':'Pavel Bobkou',
     'subjects':
        {'math':3,'language':8,'history':4,'foreignl':9}},
    {'name':'Ann Sokolova',
     'subjects':
        {'math':10,'language':8,'history':4,'foreignl':8}}
]
```

Сначала я получаю значения для каждого студента, после получаю в каком порядке мне эти оценки записались в список `out`.

Я хочу сделать с оценками по предметам для каждого студента следующее: ту которую студент получил на экзамене*0.7 и прибавить оценки всех остальных студентов по этому же предмету.

Проблема в том, что я сделал и это работает только в отношении первого студента, но не идет работать дальше, точнее он думает что все закончилось.

Вот код с комментариями:

```
GRADEBOOK = [
    {'name':'Maksim Fedartsou',
     'subjects':
        {'math':9,'language':5,'history':8,'foreignl':9}},
    {'name':'Pavel Bobkou',
     'subjects':
        {'math':3,'language':8,'history':4,'foreignl':9}},
    {'name':'Ann Sokolova',
     'subjects':
        {'math':10,'language':8,'history':4,'foreignl':8}}
]

out= []

for l in range( len( GRADEBOOK ) ):
    b = [ i for i in GRADEBOOK[l]['subjects'].values() ]
    out.append( b )
kl = GRADEBOOK[0]['subjects'].keys()
mark  = 0
marks = []

for n in range(4): # B out я вывел оценки студентов,здесь они должны посчитаться для рейтинговой, то есть для каждого
    for i in out:  #Студента 4 оценки, сколько и предметов, но почему он считает только для одного первого студента,
        if mark==0:#u как сделать чтоб считал для всех дальше
            mark= i[n]*0.7
        else:
            mark+= i[n]
    marks.append( mark )#этот список должен содержать вложенные списки с рейтинговыми оценками для студентов
    mark = 0

print( marks )
```

Comment: Оформьте, пожалуйста, код текстом, а не скриншотом. очень красочно и красиво, но не делайте так.

Comment: А, ладно, мне же все равно делать нечего :) Сделал распознавание клевого скриншота с подсветкой и комментариями.

Answer (score 1):

Замечания по коду:

1. Нельзя так перебирать словари. Вы перебираете несколько словарей с одинаковыми ключами, но не гарантируется, что порядок ключей будет постоянным. Что-то вроде этого надо писать:

   ```
   sciences = GRADEBOOK[0]['subjects'].keys()
   for l in range( len( GRADEBOOK ) ):
       b = [ GRADEBOOK[l]['subjects'][i] for i in sciences ]
   ```
2. Вы написали корректный алгоритм на человеческом языке, но при переводе на язык программирования Вы реализовали что-то совершенно другое. Если Вы читаете человекопонятный алгоритм и понимаете, что он корректно решит задачу, то не ломайте алгоритм, а просто перекладывайте его желаемым языком программирования.
3. Вы писали `Я хочу сделать с оценками по предметам для каждого студента следующее`. Из этой фразы, написанной на обычном русском языке, следует, что первым циклом перебора будет перебор студентов, вложен в него будет перебор предметов.
4. Вы писали `ту которую студент получил на экзамене*0.7 и прибавить оценки всех остальных студентов по этому же предмету` это же означает, что нужно сделать еще один перебор- перебор оценок *по этому же предмету*. При этом надо учитывать, что если оценка принадлежит этому студенту, то ее надо умножить на 0.7, а если другому, то просто прибавить к имеемой сумме.

Пояснение действий в комментариях:

```
GRADEBOOK = [
    {'name':'Maksim Fedartsou',
     'subjects':
        {'math':9,'language':5,'history':8,'foreignl':9}},
    {'name':'Pavel Bobkou',
     'subjects':
        {'math':3,'language':8,'history':4,'foreignl':9}},
    {'name':'Ann Sokolova',
     'subjects':
        {'math':10,'language':8,'history':4,'foreignl':8}}
]

sciences = GRADEBOOK[0]['subjects'].keys() # ['math', 'foreignl', 'history', 'language']

result = {}               # полностью создаем результирующую структуру и заполняем
for student in GRADEBOOK: # ее начальными значениями - нулями
    result[ student['name'] ] = {}
    for i in sciences: result[ student['name'] ][i] = 0
# result = {'Pavel Bobkou': {'foreignl': 0, 'math': 0, 'history': 0, 'language': 0}, 'Ann Sokolova': {'foreignl': 0, 'math': 0, 'history': 0, 'language': 0}, 'Maksim Fedartsou': {'foreignl': 0, 'math': 0, 'history': 0, 'language': 0}}

for student in GRADEBOOK: # перебираем студентов
    for i in sciences:    # перебираем предметы обучения
        for j in GRADEBOOK: # снова перебираем студентов, но на самом деле брать будем только его оценку по перебираемому предмету обучения
            if student == j: result[ student['name'] ][i]+= j['subjects'][i]*0.7 # если оценка принадлежит перебираемому студенту, то умножаем ее на 0.7 и прибавляем к итогу
            else: result[ student['name'] ][i]+= j['subjects'][i] # не принадлежит ему - просто прибавляем

print(result)
```

Результат:

```
{
  'Maksim Fedartsou': {'foreignl': 23.3, 'history': 13.6, 'math': 19.3, 'language': 19.5},
  'Ann Sokolova': {'foreignl': 23.6, 'history': 14.8, 'math': 19.0, 'language': 18.6},
  'Pavel Bobkou': {'foreignl': 23.3, 'history': 14.8, 'math': 21.1, 'language': 18.6}
}
```